# Entity Framework Code First - Manual Change To Database Table

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

We have adopted a code first approach which we like well enough.  However,  we have encountered on "procedural issue"  our SQL DBA likes to make changes to the database via SQL Management Studio.  He can communicate these changes to us and we can make the changes in our model.  This works fine if we are just changing the type of a an existing field.  However, if a column is added to the table first, yes I know its called code first ;-),  and then add that property to our class we run into issues - as we are told our model has changed,  we run update database and then we are told that the field already exists.   What is the best work around in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to delete the __MigrationHistory table if you're using EF6.  If you're using a previous version you'll need to delete the __MigrationHistory table and the EdmMetadata table.